# dynamic class creation in python

Tags: python

I want to create this class by dynamically:

```
class CreateAgent(show.ShowOne):
    """Create compute agent command"""

    log = logging.getLogger(__name__ + ".CreateAgent")

    def get_parser(self, prog_name):
        parser = super(CreateAgent, self).get_parser(prog_name)
        parser.add_argument(
            "os",
            metavar="<os>",
            help="Type of OS")
        parser.add_argument(
            "architecture",
            metavar="<architecture>",
            help="Type of architecture")
        parser.add_argument(
            "version",
            metavar="<version>",
            help="Version")
        parser.add_argument(
            "url",
            metavar="<url>",
            help="URL")
        parser.add_argument(
            "md5hash",
            metavar="<md5hash>",
            help="MD5 hash")
        parser.add_argument(
            "hypervisor",
            metavar="<hypervisor>",
            help="Type of hypervisor",
            default="xen")
        return parser

    def take_action(self, parsed_args):
        self.log.debug("take_action(%s)", parsed_args)
        compute_client = self.app.client_manager.compute
        args = (
            parsed_args.os,
            parsed_args.architecture,
            parsed_args.version,
            parsed_args.url,
            parsed_args.md5hash,
            parsed_args.hypervisor
        )
        agent = compute_client.agents.create(*args)._info.copy()
        return zip(*sorted(six.iteritems(agent)))
```

I went through many links but could find resources for dynamic class creation of classes with basic variables declarations and function.

```
class Foo(object):
    x = 10
    y = 20
    def get_x(self):
        return self.x
    def get_y(self):
        return self.y
```

Dynamic class creation can be done as:

```
Bar = type(
       'Bar',
       (object,),
       dict(
            x = 10,
            y = 20,
            get_x=lambda self:self.x,
            get_y=lambda self:self.y
        ) 
       )
```

But i don't know how to crete CreateAent class and define its functions dynamically..

This is the code that i have written:

```
def create_model(name, base=None, fields=None):
    model = type(name, base, fields)

    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fields = {
        'os': str,
        'architecture': str,
        'version': int,
        'url': str,
        'md5hash': int,
        'hypervisor': int,
        }
    model = create_model('CreateAgent', ('Showone',), fields)
    model.os = "windows"
    print model.os
```

1. It gives me the following error:

   TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict)   subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
2. I don't know how to define get_parser function.

PS: Some hints will be really helpful

Comment: generally you'd make some sort of a `CreateAgentMaker` function that returned a new class with your attributes. You can even use `@classmethod` to do it as `CreateAgent.dynamic_from_string("name",(parents,), {"key":"value", "attri":"butes"})`

Comment: @AdamSmith I am mainly confused as to how to dynamically define class functions ? Can you help me with that

Comment: Give me a concrete example. What function you're trying to build from what arguments and we'll work on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `type()` command where you have `(object,),` you want to have

```
(show.ShowOne, object),
```

and where you have `dict(...)` you could also you an already existing dictionary:

```
def some_func(self):
    do_something()

cls_dict['some_func'] = some_func
```

and then your `Bar` creation would look like:

```
# towards the top of your file
import show

# somewhere else in your file...
Bar = type(
        'Bar',
        (show.ShowOne, object),
        cls_dict,
        )
```

Comment: It gives error  NameError: name 'show' is not defined

Comment: You have to `import show` prior to that line, same as you would for a normal class construction.